# calling external js file from html

Tags: javascript

I am not that good in code but I want to learn it
but now I have this problem

in my index.html I have this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/initresize.js" ></script>
```

and then in the same file
I have this

```
 <input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Click Me!" />
```

I now that the file path is correct because when I comment out the src line my website looks weird. (no background etc)

but I get this error when pressing the button
"test is not defined"

this is my **initresize.js**

```
function test() 
{
        alert('Button clicked!');
}
```

Comment: where are you adding your script tag?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/27998684/

Comment: @GauravDave — It doesn't really matter, the JS doesn't try to access the DOM at all.

Comment: the script tag is between my head tags

Comment: "when I command out the src line my website looks weird. (no background etc)" — Since what you claim is your initresize.js file doesn't do anything that could effect that, you clearly haven't shown us something truly representative of what initresize.js does.

Comment: hope someone can help me

Comment: you can watch both scripts here if you need to

initresize.js
http://pastebin.com/J2fFu3Pt

and index.html
http://pastebin.com/2WAfTVM9

Comment: You can try to change function name like `test2()`.. sometimes this type error i have faced..

Comment: nope doesnt work then i get test2 is not defined

Comment: May be java-script is  disabled by browser..

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik  — If that was the case, then the rest of the JS that the OP says works wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `test` inside another function, so it is scoped to that function instead of being a global.

Define it outside other functions if you want it to be a global.

(Better yet, don't. Use JavaScript event binding instead 90s-style event attributes).

Comment: hi but when i even have it in a empty javascript file it doesnt work

Comment: Again - it does when I do it: http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/27998684/ — Try producing a *reduced* test case that you can include in your question and exhibits your problem. So far you've shown us a test case that has been reduced so much that the problem no longer exists, and a massive page which does a huge pile of irrelevant things.

Comment: yeah now it also works on my end 
with an empty script and then include it in the html file

Comment: hi

Maybe you can help me i need when i press the button that functino bodyresize() starts but where do i need to putt that in the initresize.js so it will work when i press  a button in index.html
because i cant putt it out of the function because then it says $body is not defined